# How do I squash all commit history and push into another remote repository?

Tags: git, github, rebase, squash

I have not been able to figure out after much trying. I have two local branches, `master` and `tests`. I have two corresponding remote branches with the same repo, `origin/master`, `origin/tests`. I have another remote branch `public/master`. I have some pushed in commit history on both local `master` and remote `origin/master`. Now, I want to squash all the commits of `origin/master` and push into the remote branch `public/master`. I can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried doing `rebase` on a new local branch but it didn't work.

Comment: what doeas "didnt'w work" means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reset to your first commit, then amend, finally force push.

```
git pull origin master
git checkout master
git reset --soft <my-first-commit>
git commit --amend -m "New commit message"
git push public master --force-with-lease
```

If the last command gives a "stale info" error, either

- run `git fetch public master` before the last command, or
- run `git push --force-with-lease public +master` instead of the last command.

You can find your first commit like this:

```
git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD
```

Comment: The last command (`git push public master --force-with-lease`) gives error.
`! [rejected]        master -> master (stale info)`
The public/master also has some content in it. But that should not matter.

Comment: Okay. It worked. But I needed to do `git pull public master` before pushing. So, please add that command, and I'll accept the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @soham.m17 Sure. I used `fetch` instead of `pull`, though, because we only need to communicate with the remote to update our stale info. We do not actually need to pull. I also gave another option that is likely to work.

Comment: Okay. For others and future reference, this is what I used: `git pull public master --allow-unrelated-histories`

Answer (score 1):

Could also work by checking out an orphan branch (which will carry the current working tree to make the very first commit), and then you can push into whatever remote you feel like.

Comment: But that will squash all the commit history that I have made in the other remote branch.

Comment: Is that a question or a comment? If it's a question: if you want to replace the content of what is your new branch into a remote branch, just use ```push --force```. If it's a comment: Your remote branch won't be touched until you push something into it.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say, that will *not* squash all the commit history.

Comment: what do you mean? If you do an "orphan" checkout, the branch will have _no_ commits in its history. So if you commit, you will get the "very first" commit on the branch (which is just like a squash... minus the comments).

Comment: Well, I tried that but it was taking all my commit history from the different branch. May be, I was making some mistake. But I am not sure. The upper commands work pretty well.